# Changing marker icon from onEachFeature instead of pointToLayer using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, layers, markers, icon

I'm referencing external data, matching it up with particular fields in feature.properties and using that to decide which layer to put the feature in, all of this from inside the `onEachFeature` part.

```
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
...
if (condition1)
  layer.addTo(layer1);
else if (condition2)
  layer.addTo(layer2);
else ...
}
```

I want to set different icons / markers also in the same process. But I see that custom markers are usually set in the `pointToLayer` part, like:

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
  ..
  if(condition1) return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon1});
  else if(condition2) return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon2});
  else ...
}
```

(assume that icon1 and icon2 have already been defined as `new L.icon({ .... })` )

It's going to get really repetitive and processor/network-consuming to reference the external data all over again in `pointToLayer`.

Is there a way I can define the feature's icon from the `onEachFeature` part itself and not have to go through `pointToLayer` ?

And even the other way around :

Is it possible to do the things you'd normally do in `onEachFeature`, in `pointToLayer` instead?

The `layer` argument isn't there in most uses.. can it be passed in?

Does leaflet loop through each feature for `pointToLayer` the same way it does for `onEachFeature` ?

Comment: not sure if this works: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260852/switch-icons-on-geojson-file-in-leaflet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#marker-seticon) can help.

Use the setIcon method in each condition:

```
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
...
if (condition1) {
  layer.setIcon(icon1);
  layer.addTo(layer1);
}
else if (condition2) {
  layer.setIcon(icon2);
  layer.addTo(layer2);
}
else ...
}
```

Comment: So I guess this means each different Icon Style has to go in a separate layer? Is there a way of having multiple icon styles in the one layer?

Comment: @LeasMaps sure, just do `layer.addTo(layer1)` everywhere. They'll all be in the same layer then.