# Switch icons on geojson file in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, icon

In Leaflet I would like to assign different icons to my Point of Interests based on attribute "tipo" in geojson file:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "Fontana dei Colli", "tipo": "fontana", "img_id": "colli", "description": "Via Campasso", "image_url": "img/fontane/FontanaDeiColli.jpg", "timestamp": null, "begin": null, "end": null, "altitudeMode": null, "tessellate": -1, "extrude": 0, "visibility": -1, "drawOrder": null, "icon": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 10.48693469784657, 45.39481875814014, 0.0 ] } },
```

This is my js code:

```
function PoIstile(feature, layer) {
switch(feature.properties["tipo"].toString()) {
        case "fontana":
            return {
            icon : L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'icons/fontana-small.png',
                iconSize:     [22, 30], // size of the icon
                iconAnchor:   [22, 22], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                popupAnchor:  [-3, -26] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor    
            }),
            }
            break;
        case "chiesa":
            return {
            icon : L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'icons/chiesa-small.png',
                iconSize:     [22, 30], // size of the icon
                iconAnchor:   [22, 22], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                popupAnchor:  [-3, -26] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor    
            }),
            }
            break;              
            }       
layer.bindPopup("<h4 class='custom-popup'>"+feature.properties.Name+"</h4><br><img src="+feature.properties.image_url+" width=100%/>");
};
var PoI = L.geoJson(PoI, {
onEachFeature: PoIstile
});
```

It doesn't work but it doesn't return any errors in console, but I can't find the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass a `pointToLayer` function in the GeoJSON options object to create your custom markers. It should be something like (not tested but it should work)

```
var PoIjson = "...";

function PoIstile(feature, latlng) {
    switch(feature.properties["tipo"]) {
        case "fontana":
            var fontanaIcon = new L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'icons/fontana-small.png',
                iconSize:     [22, 30], // size of the icon
                iconAnchor:   [22, 22], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                popupAnchor:  [-3, -26] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor    
            });
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: fontanaIcon});
        case "chiesa":
            var chiesaIcon = new L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'icons/chiesa-small.png',
                iconSize:     [22, 30], // size of the icon
                iconAnchor:   [22, 22], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                popupAnchor:  [-3, -26] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor    
            });
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: chiesaIcon});              
        }       
};

var PoI = L.geoJson(PoIjson, {
    pointToLayer: PoIstile,
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("<h4 class='custom-popup'>" + feature.properties.Name + "</h4><br><img src=" + feature.properties.image_url + " width=100%/>");
    }
});
```